# How do I call a role from within another role in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

My playbook runs a list of roles:

```
roles:
  - common
  - postgres
  - nginx
  - supervisord
  - { role: deploy_app,  app_name: myapp }
  - { role: deploy_app,  app_name: otherapp }
```

I have another role, `celery`, that I only want to run when the app named `myapp` is created using `deploy_app`. I was thinking I should pass a parameter into the role like this:

```
- { role: deploy_app,  app_name: myapp, celery: yes }
```

Then within my `deploy_app` role, I would use a `when` conditional:

```
- name: create celery worker for application
  <RUN ROLE HERE>
  when: '{{ celery }}' == 'yes'
```

How can I conditionally run a role from within a task list?

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html ?

Answer (score 5):

I think [ansible depenencies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-role-dependencies) would help here. Just create a
`/meta/main.yml` inside your role with the following:

```
---
dependencies:
  - { role: celery, tags: ["sometag"], when: "celery == 'yes'" }
```

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants `deploy_app` to run *before* `celery`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to not call from within a playbook and either use a condition in your entry books

```
- { role: celery, tags: ["sometag"], when: "celery == 'yes'" }
```

or simply convert it into a group of tasks in a file and do a conditional import

Hope that helps.