# include tasks from another role in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm designing a kind of playbook lib with individual tasks

so in the usual roles repo, I have something like:

```
roles
├── common
│   └── tasks
│       ├── A.yml
│       ├── B.yml
│       ├── C.yml
│       ├── D.yml
│       ├── login.yml
│       ├── logout.yml
│       └── save.yml
├── custom_stuff_workflow
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
└── other_stuff_workflow
    └── tasks
        └── main.yml
```

my main.yml in custom_stuff_workflow then contain something like:

```
---

- include: login.yml
- include: A.yml
- include: C.yml
- include: save.yml
- include: logout.yml
```

and this one in the other workflow:

```
---

- include: login.yml
- include: B.yml
- include: A.yml
- include: D.yml
- include: save.yml
- include: logout.yml
```

I can't find a way to do it in a natural way:
one way that worked was having all tasks in a single role and tagging the relevant tasks while including a custom_stuff_workflow

The problem I have with that is that tags cannot be set in the calling playbook: it's only to be set at command line
as I'm distributing this ansible repo with many people in the company, I can't rely on command line invocations (it would be nice to have a `#!` header in yml to be processed by `ansible-playbook` command)

I could also copy the relevant tasks (inside common in the above tree) in each workflow, but I don't want to repeat them around

Can someone see a solution to achieve what I'd like without repeating the tasks over different roles?

I guess the corner stone of my problem is that I define tasks as individual and it looks not natural in ansible...

Thanks a lot

PS: note that the tasks in the workflow have to be done in specific order and the only natural steps to abstract would be the login and save/logout

PPS: I've seen this question [How do I call a role from within another role in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078333/how-do-i-call-a-role-from-within-another-role-in-ansible) but it does not solve my problem as it's invoking a full role and not a subset of the tasks in a role

Comment: as per https://coderwall.com/p/dlsjya/executable-playbooks, we can put a shebang comment on top of the yml file, but again nothing prevents some colleague to run directly `ansible-playbook` on the file instead of running it as an executable (on top of portability issues)

Comment: maybe the command line can be a helper. I use a perl script to run diffrent playbooks. (not exactly the same). The call from the script looks like: `ansible-playbook name_of_playbook --extra-vars "lots of vars" `, if it would be possible for you to specify the way your colleagues use it, thats maybe a way.

Comment: indeed http://stackoverflow.com/users/4503915/thofin, but if I can find a native solution it would be much nicer

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Just in case someone else bumps into this, version **2.2** of Ansible now has `include_role`. You can now do something like this:

```yaml
---
- name: do something
  include_role:
    name: common
    tasks_from: login
```

Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html).

Comment: [This doesn't work inside handlers](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20493). For those, you'll still need to use part (2) from tehK's answer.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. With this command we're now able to create kind of shared task library. There's much more place for DRY principle in ansible now.

Comment: Handlers are now included in Ansible 2.8

Comment: You can also use this in an ad hoc manner with `ansible ... -m include_role -a "name=common tasks_from=login"`

Comment: so this works when called from a task in a role . eg I'm in role "config hardware" and I need to reuse a playbook from role "install os" called "reboot.yml". this will work for that case?

Answer (score 49):

Yes, Ansible doesn't really like tasks as individual components. I think it wants you to use roles, but I can see why you wouldn't want to use roles for simple, reusable tasks.

I currently see two possible solutions:

### 1. Make those task-files into roles and use dependencies

Then you could do something like this in e.g. custom_stuff_workflow

```
dependencies:
  - { role: login }
```

See: https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html#role-dependencies

### 2. Use include with "hardcoded" paths to the task files

```
- include: ../../common/tasks/login.yml
```

That worked pretty well in a short test playbook I just did. Keep in mind, you can also use parameters etc. in those includes.

See: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_reuse.html

I hope I understood that question correctly and this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer tehk, I've tried these 2 solutions but obviously it's not perfect
I may go for the 2nd one, but the hardcoded path is really not something appealing

Comment: The first option is really good. It's clear what each role does and forces you to break your project up into smaller modules

Comment: If I understand correctly, dependencies are not flexible: they run *before* the role. With 'include' you can run the included code at any step inside your role.

Comment: include supports parameter. But is there any way to use `register` with include?

Comment: I have faced similar issue and the 2nd options quite works... but it is still feels like a walkaround.

Comment: After reading what you guys tried, I am about to symlink the task files instead of hardcode the path. Does it have any obvious downside that I missed?

Comment: I think the 2nd option has the benefit (or downside) of using the local files directories, in the role including the tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in variable `playbook_dir` to include tasks from other roles.

```
- name: "Create SSL certificates."
  include_tasks: "{{ playbook_dir }}/roles/common/tasks/ssl.yml"
  with_items: "{{ domains }}"
```

The `ssl.yml` is in the `common` role. It can have any number of tasks; also, passing variables like the example is possible.

Comment: Is this still working? I got `ERROR! 'include_tasks' is not a valid attribute for a Play` with my ansible v2.16.2.

Answer (score 1):

Using `include_role:` with option `tasks_from` is a good idea. However this still includes parts of the role. For example it loads role vars and meta dependencies. If `apply` is used to apply `tags` to an included file, then same tags are applied to `meta` dependencies. Also, the ansible output lists as the included role's name in its output, which is confusing.

It is possible to dynamically locate a role and include a file using `first_found`. One can find the role path searching `DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH` and load a file from `tasks` folder. Ansible uses the same variable when sarching a role, so long as the role is in a path that Ansible can find, then the file will be loaded.

This method is as dynamic as using `include_role` with option `tasks_from`

Example:

```
- name: Include my_tasks.yml from my_ansible_role
  include_tasks: "{{lookup('first_found', params)}}"
  vars:
    params:
      files: my_ansible_role/tasks/my_tasks.yml
      paths: "{{ lookup('config', 'DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH') }}"
```