# How to Include task from another role in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to include a task from a different role.

I would not want to hardcode it like

```
- name : Set topology based on Jenkins job name
  include: ../../pre-req/tasks/set-topo.yml
  tags: core
```

Is there a way to do this with dependency? I tried creating a meta directory with files and tasks, somehow it' s not getting triggered.

something like this

```
vim roles/pre-req/meta/main.yml

---
allow_duplicates: yes
dependencies:
  - { role: topo, tags: ['core'] }
```

Comment: this is kind of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30192490/include-tasks-from-another-role-in-ansible-playbook

Comment: @HenrikPingel yes it is but the solution 1 mentioned, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would not want to hardcode it like

Why not?  You want to include a task, and that's how you include a task.

If what you want to do is include the entire other role, Ansible 2.2 (released yesterday) added [`include_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html).